Bazel build failing after adding ygot
After adding ygot package github.com/openconfig/ygot v0.29.20, I am getting below error
bazel build //...
ERROR: no such package '@@com_github_openconfig_gnmi//value': BUILD file not found in directory 'value' of external repository @@com_github_openconfig_gnmi. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/0b903048f40c7721c45e60c73f47d067/external/com_github_openconfig_ygot/ygot/BUILD.bazel:3:11: no such package '@@com_github_openconfig_gnmi//value': BUILD file not found in directory 'value' of external repository @@com_github_openconfig_gnmi. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '@@com_github_openconfig_ygot//ygot:ygot'

